# C++ Initializing and Functions from Derived Class from Vector of Pointer Base

Tags: c++

I have a problem where I have 2 classes, Word and Noun. Noun is derived from Word.

All Words and Nouns are to be stored in a single vector hence why I require it being in pointer.

The problem is I can't seem to initialize or call functions from the derived class Noun.
I can pushback for a new Word but not for a Noun.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Word{
protected:
    string wordName, def, type;
public:
    Word();
    Word(string wordName, string def, string type) {
        this->wordName = wordName;
        this->def = def;
        this->type = type;
    };
    void getWord() {
        cout << wordName << endl;
    }
    void getDef() {
        cout << def << endl;
    }
    void getType() {
        cout << type << endl;
    }
};


class Noun : public Word{
public:
    Noun();
    Noun(string wordName, string type, string def);
};


int main(){
    vector <Word*> wordVector;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        string wordName, def, type;
        cin >> wordName;
        cin >> def;
        cin >> type;
        cout << endl;
        wordVector.push_back(new Noun(wordName, def, type));    //new Word(wordName, def, type) works
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        wordVector[i]->getWord();       //how do you call the function from Noun?
        wordVector[i]->getDef();
        wordVector[i]->getType();
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It comes out with 1 unresolved external symbol.

Comment: That's a linker error, not a compiler error. You forgot to write all the code.

Comment: And where do you define (implement) the `Noun` constructor?

Comment: And as far as "how do you call the function from Noun?" goes, that's what virtual methods are for.

Comment: Also, when posting questions regarding build errors, always please include the complete and unedited error output, including possible informational notes, and if possible point out the lines in *your* code where the errors are (compiler errors usually have a filename and line-number attached). And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many things wrong with this code, so allow me to present a correct, complete rewrite that does what you mean:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>   // for std::unique_ptr
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Word
{
private:
    std::string wordName, def, type;

public:
    virtual ~Word() = default;

    Word(std::string w, std::string d, std::string t)
    : wordName(std::move(w))
    , def(std::move(d))
    , type(std::move(t)) {}

    void printWord() const { std::cout << wordName << '\n'; }

    void printDef() { std::cout << def << '\n'; }

    void printType() const { std::cout << type << '\n'; }
};

class Noun : public Word
{
public:
    using Word::Word;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Word>> wordVector;

    for (int i = 0; i != 2; ++i)
    {
        std::string w, d, t;
        if (!(std::cin >> w >> d >> t))
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to read input!\n";
            continue;
        }

        wordVector.push_back(std::make_unique<Noun>(
            std::move(w), std::move(d), std::move(t)));
    }

    for (const auto& wp : wordVector)
    {
        wp->printWord();
        wp->printDef();
        wp->printType();
    }
}
```

A completely unsorted and incomplete set of issues that I corrected:

- Memory management (`std::unique_ptr`)
- Virtual destructor for deletion through base
- No nonsensical default constructors
- Inheriting constructors rather than manual forwarding
- Properly named member functions
- Const correctness
- No superfluous semicolons
- No superfluous `std::endl`
- Not `abusing namespace std`
- Range-based `for` loop
- I/O error handling
- Initialize rather than assign
- Enable move optimizations
- No raw `new`
- Correct access level for private members (exposed via member functions)

Comment: My bad. I cut some of the coding short so it would be more presentable but it made you have to correct all my errors.

Should the terminator in the for loop not be a range?
If say I were to call a function from Noun, how would I do so?

Comment: @JReno: You wouldn't *want* to do that. Your container contains words, not nouns, so you should't even be *asking* for nouns. What you really want to do is give `Word` the desired interface and allow customization of that via virtual functions.

Comment: If there were other derived classes besides Noun, and I wanted to only get Nouns, wouldn't a function 'getNoun()' returning it's name work? That way I wouldn't have to check the type of all the Words.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you just forgot to initialize the `superclass constructor`** In your `Noun` class try this

```
class Noun : public Word{
public:
    Noun();
    Noun(string wordName, string type, string def): Word(wordName, type, def){};
};
```

I have tested it and it worked.

Also theres a light modification in you main(). just a slight. so that i can see what input it is asking for.

```
int main(){
    vector <Word*> wordVector;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {

        string wordName, def, type;
        cout<< "entere name";
        cin >> wordName;
        cout<< "entere def";
        cin >> def;
        cout<< "entere type";
        cin >> type;
        cout << endl;
        wordVector.push_back(new Noun(wordName, def, type));    //new Word(wordName, def, type) works
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        wordVector[i]->getWord();       //how do you call the function from Noun?
        wordVector[i]->getDef();
        wordVector[i]->getType();
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the issue I was missing.